# IndexError: list index out of range Python error

Tags: python

My command line arguments:

python SearchString.py 10 nee

Argument 1 does not match the length. How should i handle that ?

Error: 
File "SearchString.py", line 30, in string_search
search = temp[fieldindex]
IndexError: list index out of range

```
#!usr/bin/python
import sys

def string_search():
    '''
    This function search a string in a file through index and gives the result.

    :returns: none
    :return type: none 
    :author:XYZ   

    '''
    if len(sys.argv) != 3:
        print "Enter Two Arguments Only"
        sys.exit()

    stringsrch = sys.argv[2]
    found = False
    file_name = open("passwd", "r")

    if sys.argv[1].isdigit():
        fieldindex = int(sys.argv[1])-1
    else:
       print "Enter Integer in 1st Argument"
    sys.exit()
    #fieldindex = int(sys.argv[1])-1

   for store_file in file_name:
        temp = store_file.split(":")
        search = temp[fieldindex]

        if stringsrch in search:
            print store_file
            found = True
    if not found:
        print "No String "

string_search()
```

Comment: Why not just have a line `if fieldindex >= len(temp):` with an error message?

Comment: where should i write that in code ?

Comment: Before the line with your error, `search = temp[fieldindex]`

Comment: inside the for loop ? i am an newbie

Comment: You didn't write this code?

Comment: its me only who wrote and can you please provide the answer to where i should i write ?

Comment: If you wrote the code, you should know how to check `if fieldindex >= len(temp):` and exit the program. You check similar conditions two other times in the program.

Comment: I am a newbie is not a excuse to think about the code that you are writing

Comment: @user2799617 A little irrelevant, but what an awesome votes cast you have!

Answer (score 0):

I think the code depends on how you use it.
`search = temp[fieldindex]`. From the code, your fieldindex is `9`, so you should make sure `len(temp) > 9`. Or you will get error like what you said.